# Visual Studio 2017 - measuring "Lines of code"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm unable to find a good option for my Visual Studio 2017.

I tried right clicking the projects, but there wasn't an option for "Analyze".

Just a few hours ago, I installed "Roslyn Code Analysis" using Nuget package manager. It's installed as "Archimetrics.Analysis".

How do I get "Lines of code" using this package. I have tried all the tried all the common ways of right clicking and trying to fins something but to no avail. That's why I installed this package "Roslyn" for code analysis, which is installed as "Archimetrics.Analysis".

Comment: Did you find any solution? I did find how to do a LOC count, but it doesn't count any JavaScript unfortunately

Answer (score 22):

A little hacky way that works quite well is to use a RegEx with Find in Files

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> or Edit -> Find and Replace -> Find in Files
2. Use `^(?([^\r\n])\s)*[^\s+?/]+[^\n]*$` in the 'Find what:' field
3. Check 'Use Regular Expressions'
4. Set 'Look in:' and 'Look at these file types:' to your desired search scope
5. Hit enter and scroll to the bottom after the find is complete and you'll see `Matching lines: 25843`. That's the line count

Answer (score 12):

I use the famous "Supercharger" extension and among the many functions,it has just that:

[image: Supercharger]

Result:

---

Code structure statistics for project 'SysMonitor_1'

```
C# classes        :        14
C# interfaces     :         1
C# structs        :         1
C# enums          :         0

C# functions      :        49
C# properties     :        11
```

---

Code line count  statistics for project 'SysMonitor_1'

```
C# comment lines  :       128
C# empty lines    :       105
C# pure code lines:       722
-----------------------------
Total C# lines    :       955

Non-C# lines      :       607

=============================
All lines         :     1.562
```

Comment: This is very good, but I'll just mention that it isn't free, although there is a 30-day free trial period. http://supercharger.tools/

Comment: @RenniePet there is "Community License" and is free, if not commercial use:
http://supercharger.tools/pricing.html

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Analyze -> Calculate Code Metrics -> For Solution option.

It will calculate the Maintainability Index, Cyclomatic Complexity, Depth of Inheritance, Class Coupling and Lines of Code.

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Analyze Menu Calculate Code Metrics Option]

[image: Code Metrics Result]

For Further Details, you can consult the documentation at: [Measure code maintainability with code metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-metrics-values?view=vs-2017)